# windows 10 unremoveable language keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I don't know how but suddenly a new language was added to my keyboard settings. The problem is that I can't remove it because it's not in the settings.

I want only English and Hebrew, but somehow I get:

- English
- Hebrew
- Hebrew US keyboard (this one I want to delete, it is just English)
  [image]

here are the settings:

[image]

Clicking on options I don't have the "Hebrew US keyboard" option anywhere to disable.

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate of the mentioned question. Significant details differ so that the solution given in the referred-to answer do not apply here. Sad.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: Press Win+R key and type "regedit".

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`

Create a DWORD named `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` and set it to 1.

Comment: Yes try restarting. And also try to remove it again from control panel keyboard layout settings.

Comment: try to add the hidden language as the main system language. Reboot. Switch back. And then delete the hidden language from system lang list

Comment: need to reboot the system afterwards